# get() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests, json

userinput = raw_input('Enter a keyword: ')

getparams = {'order':'desc', 'sort':'votes', 'intitle':userinput, 'site':'stackoverflow', 'filter': '!5-HwXhXgkSnzI0yfp0WqsC_-6BehEi(fRTZ7eg'}

r = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search', params=getparams)

result = json.loads(r.text)

if result['has_more'] == False:
print 'Error given.'
else:
for looping in result['items']:
    print ''
    print ''
    print 'Title:', looping['title']
    #print 'Question:', looping['body']
    print 'Link:', looping['link']
    if looping['is_answered'] == True:
       try:
          print 'Answer ID#:', looping['accepted_answer_id']
          newparams = {'order':'desc', 'sort':'votes', 'site':'stackoverflow', 'filter': '!4(Yrwr)RRK6oy2JSD'}
          newr = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/', looping['accepted_answer_id'], params=newparams)
          newresult = json.loads(newr.text)
          print newresult['items'][0]['body']
          except KeyError: print 'No answer ID found.'
    print ''
    print ''
```

I am trying to make a request such as "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/12345 (User inputs 12345)" but I don't know how to do that. And if I include a string it returns error. Help, please?

I am getting this error:

```
Enter a keyword: php


Title: How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?
Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php
Answer ID#: 60496
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./warrior.py", line 25, in <module>
newr = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/', looping['accepted_answer_id'], params=newparams)
TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Right now, we can't help, because we can't see what you're doing.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: I have updated the code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update the request line as

```
newr = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/'+str(looping['accepted_answer_id']), params=newparams)
```

you need to concatenate the looping['accepeted answer']

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! :D